# Copiar datos de libro origen después de la última fila vacía del libro destino

Tags: excel, vba

Qué tal, tengo una duda sobre como copiar datos de libro origen y pegar después de la última fila disponible de libro destino.
Anteriormente pensaba en copiar y pegar libro por libro pero optimicé la tarea haciendo un concentrado de todos estos libros para poder pegar todos esos datos en la última fila del libro destino, desconozco como poder lograr hacerlo, ya que sólo lo había conseguido copiar y pegar si el libro está vacío. 
Espero me puedan ayudar.

Comment: No pero ya logré hacerlo @Damian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qué tal, lo logré con estas dos líneas, lo pueden ajustar a sus necesidades.

```
wsCopyFrom.Range("A1:M" & wsCopyFrom.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row).Copy
wsCopyTo.Range("A" & wsCopyTo.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
```

La segunda línea te lo pega en la última fila disponible de tu libro.

Comment: LA segunda línea debería ser `wsCopyTo.Range("A" & wsCopyTo.Range("A" & wsCopyTo.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats`. Si solo pones `Rows.Count` en vez de `wsCopyTo.Rows.Count`, cogerá el número de filas de la hoja activa, que no tiene por qué ser la `wsCopyTo` (depende del resto de tu código, claro).

Comment: @ElierSánchezE-Infantes eso no es del todo cierto, todas las hojas tienen la misma cantidad de filas, a menos que estés mezclando un excel de 2003 o anterior (64k de filas) con uno posterior (1M de filas). Así que daría igual realmente referenciar de qué hoja cuentas las filas.

Comment: @Damian Cierto, es una posibilidad muy remota.